# How do I add an instance of type MyClass to an array of MyClass, declared in MyClass, inside the constructor of MyClass?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, instance

In order to keep track of instances, we have an array MyClass[] mc = new MyClass[5];

I want to save the instances of MyClass created inside this array, during the constructor call itself.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 64;
  private static int number = 0;
  private static MyClass[] classList= new MyClass[MAX_SIZE];


  public MyClass(MyClass mc) { 
    classList[number++] = mc;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyClass mc1 = new MyClass(mc1);
}
```

But this doesn't work as I get "mc1 might not be initialized" error which is expected, tbh.

Now, I know we can create another method that to save the instance of created class inside the array but this 'saving instances of class' is in class's self interest and do not want to force users of class to call this method. Hence finding a way to finish this up in the const itself.

How do I go about doing this? Thank you very much in Advance!! :)

Asking for a friend.

Comment: This is not a good design.  Keep the *Array* of the class separate from the actual class itself.

Comment: Your are passing mc1 as argument to constructor which only gets initialised when Object is created .and for  object to be created it needs an initialised value for mc1 at least null in constructor so it is kind of deadlock here.So you can't use this

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your constructor:

```
classList[number++]  = this;
```

And simply not have that mc parameter.

But of course, the whole idea is bad practice. A class has a distinct responsibility. You are putting another responsibility in it (to count / list instances). So besides the fact that your code easily creates a memory leak, it also violates the single responsibility principle.

If you want to keep track of certain objects, then have a *another* class that holds such lists and explicitly register newly created objects there.

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I need. I will keep in mind about the class design practice and try to implement it instead of doing this.

Comment: It is OK for a class to keep track of its instances. See for example Integer.

Comment: A cache isn't the same as a list that keeps a hard reference for each instance. Beyond that, you often want value semantics when dealing with well, numerical numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do better using a list, such as an ArrayList. The performance of ArrayList is not much worse than that of an array.

public class ArrayTest {
    private static List classList = new ArrayList<>();

```
public ArrayTest() {
    classList.add(this);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ArrayTest mc1 = new ArrayTest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using `MyClass mc` as a parameter in your constructor is a mistake. There is no way for that `MyClass` instance to be initialized as it keeps requiring another previous already initialized instance. As someone before me pointed out you can use `... = this` and work around it, but its not advised. Just write the extra method.